# How to access Kafka in docker machine from local?

Tags: docker

I ran this command to run Kafka and Zookeeper in a docker machine:

**Create the docker machine:**

docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default

**Make the machine active:**

eval $(docker-machine env default)

**Does this command below run Kafka and Zookeeper in the docker machine I created above?**

docker run -d --name kafka -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active`` --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 rahulagrawal/kafka

I want to know how I can connect to the Kafka broker running in `docker-machine ip` which is `192.168.99.100`.

Comment: So you are asking which tool you should use to connect or you are using something and not able to connect?

Comment: Yes I am asking which tool to use to connect and also if the above `docker run...` command installs kafka and zookeeper on my docker machine or on localhost? I used this: https://hub.docker.com/r/rahulagrawal/kafka/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this command below run Kafka and Zookeeper in the docker machine
>   I created above?

Yes the container is running inside the docker-machine you created.

> I want to know how I can connect to the Kafka broker running in
>   docker-machine ip which is 192.168.99.100

The kafka broker can be reached using 192.168.99.100:9092

Comment: When I log into the `virutalbox` using `ssh 192.168.99.100` kafka doesn't seem to be installed? But when I run `docker exec -i -t kafka bash` it somehow shows up kafka. Is that because in the second command I am running a bash shell inside of the container that is on 192.168.99.100?

Comment: This is expected. Kafka is available inside the container and not inside the virtual machine. The virtual machine is just runnng the container. When you exec you are inside the container(which is inside the vm). When you ssh you are just in the vm and not in the container.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! For some reason when I run Kafka on my local machine it is not working. Kafka on my docker-machine shouldn't affect my Kafka I am running on my local machine correct? I am trying to perform Kafka mirroring from my Kafka in docker to my Kafka in my local machine.